# How to load trained caffe model in h5 format to c++ caffe net?

Tags: neural-network, protocol-buffers, deep-learning, caffe, hdf5

Normally trained caffe model are in `.caffemodel` extension and actually they are in `binary protobuf` format.

Any idea how to load a caffe model in `hdf5` format to caffe net in c++?

I have a model trained with python caffe in `hdf5` format.

My application is in c++ using caffe c++ version and I prefer to use c++ than python.

How to read the model in caffe trained model in hdf5 format to c++ caffe net?

I know that caffe has hdf5data layer inside.
Is there a sample program for that?

**EDIT:**

I used CopyTrainedLayersFromHDF5() api and got following runtime errors.

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.11) thread 140737353775552:
  #000: ../../../src/H5G.c line 463 in H5Gopen2(): unable to open group
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Can't open object
  #001: ../../../src/H5Gint.c line 320 in H5G__open_name(): group not found
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Object not found
  #002: ../../../src/H5Gloc.c line 430 in H5G_loc_find(): can't find object
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Object not found
  #003: ../../../src/H5Gtraverse.c line 861 in H5G_traverse(): internal path traversal failed
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Object not found
  #004: ../../../src/H5Gtraverse.c line 641 in H5G_traverse_real(): traversal operator failed
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Callback failed
  #005: ../../../src/H5Gloc.c line 385 in H5G_loc_find_cb(): object 'data' doesn't exist
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Object not found
F0220 15:32:14.272573 24576 net.cpp:811] Check failed: data_hid >= 0 (-1 vs. 0) Error reading weights from model_800000.h5
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7ffff64afdcd  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @     0x7ffff64b1d08  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x7ffff64af963  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x7ffff64b263e  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @     0x7ffff691c3a3  caffe::Net<>::CopyTrainedLayersFromHDF5()
    @           0x40828d  ExtractFeature::ExtractFeature()
    @           0x40ce78  main
    @     0x7ffff5bf8f45  __libc_start_main
    @           0x4080c9  (unknown)

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff5c0dc37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) cd 
[17]+  Stopped                 gdb ./endtoendlib
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
>>h5ls model_800000.h5 command gave me

conv1                    Group
conv2                    Group
forget_gate              Dataset {1, 250, 1, 1274}
inception_3a             Group
inception_3b             Group
inception_4a             Group
inception_4b             Group
inception_4c             Group
inception_4d             Group
inception_4e             Group
inception_5a             Group
inception_5b             Group
input_gate               Dataset {1, 250, 1, 1274}
input_value              Dataset {1, 250, 1, 1274}
ip_bbox_unscaled0.p0     Dataset {4, 250}
ip_bbox_unscaled0.p1     Dataset {4}
ip_bbox_unscaled1.p0     Dataset {4, 250}
ip_bbox_unscaled1.p1     Dataset {4}
ip_bbox_unscaled2.p0     Dataset {4, 250}
ip_bbox_unscaled2.p1     Dataset {4}
ip_bbox_unscaled3.p0     Dataset {4, 250}
ip_bbox_unscaled3.p1     Dataset {4}
ip_bbox_unscaled4.p0     Dataset {4, 250}
ip_bbox_unscaled4.p1     Dataset {4}
ip_conf0.p0              Dataset {2, 250}
ip_conf0.p1              Dataset {2}
ip_conf1.p0              Dataset {2, 250}
ip_conf1.p1              Dataset {2}
ip_conf2.p0              Dataset {2, 250}
ip_conf2.p1              Dataset {2}
ip_conf3.p0              Dataset {2, 250}
ip_conf3.p1              Dataset {2}
ip_conf4.p0              Dataset {2, 250}
ip_conf4.p1              Dataset {2}
output_gate              Dataset {1, 250, 1, 1274}
post_fc7_conv.p0         Dataset {1024, 1024, 1, 1}
post_fc7_conv.p1         Dataset {1024}
```

Comment: Yeah I checked the .h5 file and it is in binary format.

Comment: but is the binary format correct? if you `h5ls model_80000.h5` what do you get? it appears as if caffe expects the file to have a `'data'` dataset that is not there...

Comment: h5ls command gave me as in EDIT1. I see Dataset.

Comment: how did you save this `model_80000.h5` file? was it saved by caffe? caffe `net.ToHDF5(...)` method that saves the weights into hdf5 file saves the parameters into `data` (and optionally `diff`) datasets. Your file does not have this dataset. you can try and manually "tweak" the file and add `data/` to all datasets in the file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered the `net` object method [`void CopyTrainedLayersFromHDF5(const string trained_filename);`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/include/caffe/net.hpp#L116)? It seems like it does what you are looking for.

As for `"HDF5Data"` layer: you are confusing two things here. The hdf5 file you have stores the **trained parameters** of the net. In contrast, `"HDF5Data"` layer stores the **training examples** used for training the net.

Comment: yeah your solution is correct. I need to work on my h5 file so that it can be loaded to c++ caffe.